# How to definitely remove/uninstall Bluetooh drivers in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I want to switch from QUALCOMM to Realtek but whenever I uninstall Bluetooth driver from device management and run the Realtek installation it throws an error that "There are unauthorized Bluetooth adapters in your system, Please remove or disable the devices", and no matter how many times I try to uninstall the previous Bluetooth driver it just reappears on its own would appreciate if you could help me through this

Also the reason I want to switch drivers is that with the Qualcomm drivers my Bluetooth wont show any available devices to pair also I have tried troubleshooting, fixing the services settings and nothing seems to work idk if its a software issue or hardware(shed some light on this issue as well) :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the driver aspects of your questoin, but the following **PowerShell** code will allow you to interactively delete previously saved devices. So try removing all devices and see if that helps.

```
$Source = @"
   [DllImport("BluetoothAPIs.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
   static extern UInt32 BluetoothRemoveDevice(IntPtr pAddress);

   public static UInt32 Unpair(UInt64 BTAddress) {
      GCHandle pinnedAddr = GCHandle.Alloc(BTAddress, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      IntPtr pAddress     = pinnedAddr.AddrOfPinnedObject();
      UInt32 result       = BluetoothRemoveDevice(pAddress);
      pinnedAddr.Free();
      return result;
   }
"@

Function Get-BTDevice {
    Get-PnpDevice -class Bluetooth |
      ?{$_.HardwareID -match 'DEV_'} |
         select Status, Class, FriendlyName, HardwareID,
            # Extract device address from HardwareID
            @{N='Address';E={[uInt64]('0x{0}' -f $_.HardwareID[0].Substring(12))}}
}

################## Execution Begins Here ################

$BTR       = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Source -Name "BTRemover"  -Namespace "BStuff" -PassThru
$BTDevices = @(Get-BTDevice) # Force array if null or single item

Do {
   If ($BTDevices.Count) {
      "`n******** Bluetooth Devices ********`n" | Write-Host
      For ($i=0; $i -lt $BTDevices.Count; $i++) {
         ('{0,5} - {1}' -f ($i+1), $BTDevices[$i].FriendlyName) | Write-Host
      }
      $selected = Read-Host "`nSelect a device to remove (0 to Exit)"
      If ([int]$selected -in 1..$BTDevices.Count) {
         'Removing device: {0}' -f $BTDevices[$Selected-1].FriendlyName | Write-Host
         $Result = $BTR::Unpair($BTDevices[$Selected-1].Address)
         If (!$Result) {"Device removed successfully." | Write-Host}
         Else {"Sorry, an error occured." | Write-Host}
      }
   }
   Else {
      "`n********* No devices found ********" | Write-Host
   }
} While (($BTDevices = @(Get-BTDevice)) -and [int]$selected)
```

Copy and paste the entire code block into a **PowerShell** console window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll then be presented with a list of all saved devices:

```
******** Bluetooth Devices ********

    1 - Chill Out
    2 - Pixel 6
    3 - LG HBS730
    4 - Pixel 6
    5 - Pixel 6
    6 - Pixel 6

Select a device to remove (0 to Exit):
```

After deleting a device, an update list will appear until all devices are deleted or you press <kbd>0</kbd> to exit.